# How to use puts with multiple variable in one argument in Tcl?

Tags: loops, printing, tcl, puts

I have a series of list like a1, a2, a3, a4, ....
I want to print them in a loop, Thus both a and i are variables. How can I do that?

This doesn't work.

```
for {set i 1}....
 puts $a$i
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you have _variables_ `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, etc?

Comment: If so, is it possible for you to switch to using an array, `a(1)`, `a(2)`, `a(3)`, etc? That's much easier than the code for reading from a variable variable…

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, each of them is sperate lists such as: set a1 [list 1 2 3 4]; set a2 [list 10 20 30 40]; set a3 [list 100 200 300 400]

Comment: That's not a showstopper. You can do `set a(1) [list 1 2 3 4]; set a(2) [list 10 20 30 40]; # ...`. Best follow @DonalFellows advise on using an array, which is a variable bundle with common prefix, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd have them in an associative array, but otherwise…

To read from a variable whose name is not constant, use the `set` command with *just one argument* instead of the `$` syntax. (This use of `set` predates `$`.)

```
for {set i 1} {$i <= 3} {incr i} {
    puts [set a$i]
}
```

However, it would be better to use an array (so the variables would effectively be named `a(1)`, `a(2)`, etc instead of `a1`, `a2`, etc). But it does mean a change to the code that creates the variables too.

```
for {set i 1} {$i <= 3} {incr i} {
    puts $a($i)
}
```

---

The other realistic option for doing access to variable variables is the `upvar` command. It's not really recommended in the global namespace, but in a procedure it's very effective.

```
proc printThree {} {
    for {set i 1} {$i <= 3} {incr i} {
        upvar 1 a$i vbl
        puts $vbl
    }
}
```

This works particularly well when doing more complex operations than just printing the value.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I want. grazie Mille!

Answer (score 0):

As list:

```
set a1 [list 1 2 3 4]
set a2 [list 10 20 30 40]
set a3 [list 100 200 300 400]
set a4 [list 1000 2000 3000 4000]

foreach i [list {*}$a1] { puts "\$a$i: [set a$i]" }
# $a1: 1 2 3 4
# $a2: 10 20 30 40
# $a3: 100 200 300 400
# $a4: 1000 2000 3000 4000
```

As array:

```
array set a {
 1 {1 2 3 4}
 2 {10 20 30 40}
 3 {100 200 300 400}
 4 {1000 2000 3000 4000}
}

parray a
# a(1) = 1 2 3 4
# a(2) = 10 20 30 40
# a(3) = 100 200 300 400
# a(4) = 1000 2000 3000 4000
```

As dict:

```
set a [dict create         \
a1 {1 2 3 4}               \
a2 {10 20 30 40}           \
a3 {100 200 300 400}       \
a4 {1000 2000 3000 4000}]  

dict for {k v} $a { puts "$k: $v" }
# a1: 1 2 3 4
# a2: 10 20 30 40
# a3: 100 200 300 400
# a4: 1000 2000 3000 4000
```

As matrix:

```
package require struct::matrix 

::struct::matrix xdata
xdata add columns 4
xdata add rows    4

xdata set rect 0 0 {
{1 2 3 4}
{10 20 30 40}
{100 200 300 400}
{1000 2000 3000 4000}
}

join [xdata get rect 0 0 end end] \n
# 1 2 3 4
# 10 20 30 40
# 100 200 300 400
# 1000 2000 3000 4000

#cleanup 
xdata destroy
```